# what is the correct way to initialize java array with a size and default value

Tags: java

In c++, I can do

```
vector<int> arr(10, 100); // arr with Size 10 and default value 100.
```

Is there a similar way (one-liner) to initialize java array with a size and default value?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-fill-java-examples/

Comment: That's not an array, that's a collection. Do you want a Java array or a Java Collection? and if the latter, which one? `ArrayList`?

Comment: If you want to initialize an `ArrayList`: `new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(10, 100))`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function. In Java, arrays are always initialized with 0 or `false` or `null`, according to type.

You can `import java.util.Arrays;` and then do:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
Arrays.fill(arr, 100);
```

Comment: If you fill in this way, It will add 100 as default for all the values.  Like this   [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100,100]

Comment: `int[] arr = IntStream.generate(() -> 100).limit(10).toArray();`

Comment: He didn't ask about a built-in function, and there is `int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};`.

Comment: I was actually asking a built-in function in c++ style.

Comment: @Nishantha Bulumulla: yes, that is what `vector<int> arr(10, 100);` does in C. He didn't ask for ascending values.

Comment: @derek No, you didn't ask for that.